# Turning Ising partition function into diagrams

Tags: graphs-and-networks

This question is about transforming an expression into a diagram.

The partition function of the Ising model for a 4×4 square lattice without a magnetic field has the form,
[image]

or

```
Z = (1+ t sigma_1 sigma_2)(1+ t sigma_2 sigma_3)(1+ t sigma_3 sigma_4)....(1+ t sigma_12 sigma_16)
```

The spin variable `sigma` can have two values, `+1` or `-1`, and all the spin variables are summed over. After expanding, the right-hand side of `Z` gives roughly 8 million terms on which only 512 contributions are non-zero. Following the [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/272657/collecting-even-power-terms-in-ising-problem) answer, these non-zero expressions can be generated by the code below:

```
z = Product[
           1 + \[Sigma][i, j] \[Sigma][i + 1, j] t, {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 4}]*
          Product[1 + \[Sigma][i, j] \[Sigma][i, j + 1] t, {i, 1, 4}, {j, 1, 
            3}]
            
rule = {u : \[Sigma][_, _]^n_ /; EvenQ[n] -> u, \[Sigma][_, _]^n_. /; OddQ[n] -> 0};
            
Z = Sum[t^(2 i) Expand[Coefficient[z, t, 2 i]], {i, 1, 10}] /. rule
```

Each of the (zero or non-zero) terms can be mapped to a diagram. For example [image]

Generating all such diagrams by hand is nearly an impossible task. Will it be possible to generate code for this that can turn each term of the partition function into a diagram and finally generate all diagrams?

Comment: Please make your question self-contained by including the definition of  `z` here. I assume that UPPERCASE `Z` and lowercase `z` are different, and that lowercase `z` is defined as in the answer to your previous question. If I do that, however, the $t^{16}$ term thus obtained only contains terms in $\sigma_1$ through $\sigma_4$ and no higher, so I cannot reproduce the expression in your image.

Comment: The best way to go would be for you to include a complete expression for your $t^{16}$ term in Mathematica code (with no omissions!). From then, somebody could help you generate a graph from that expression. A starting point could be to convert the `sigma[a_, b_] :> (a <-> b)` using `Cases` and then use Graph to generate the graph, but again, it's not easy to help if we don't have an actual expression to work on.

Comment: @ MarcoB, I am working to make it self-contained.

Comment: I don't think this is possible in your current form where you use usual, commutative multiplication between $\sigma$. Given your example in the image, there is no way to determine whether **two loops** (as shown) or only **one loop** (1–2–6–7–3–4–8–12–16–15–11–10–14–13–9–5–1) should be drawn! You have to modify the code so that it uses [`NonCommutativeMultiply`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonCommutativeMultiply.html), which will allow then to **uniquely** map a given term to the corresponding diagram.

Comment: A [visual addendum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKFOg.png) to my previous comment where I used [`FindHamiltonianCycle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindHamiltonianCycle.html).

Comment: This looks like Waerden's [decomposition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73SLp.png) of partition function into Eulerian subgraphs. So then your question becomes -- how do I visualize all Eulerian subgraphs of a graph? For special classes of graphs (perhaps for grid too), these subgraphs can be represented as a combination of much smaller number of cycles

Comment: @ Yaroslav Bulatov, You are definitely right. Following Waerden's theorem, the Ising model partition function can be mapped into the problem of counting the number of loops on a lattice. And my question is precisely about generating all such loops for a four by 4 square lattice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I have mentioned in the comments, your current code does not allow to uniquely map a given term to the diagram because you use usual multiplication (`Times`) which is commutative while $\sigma$ do not necessarily commute with each other. That is why you first have to fix the code for generating the partition function.

```
Clear[n, Z, getEdges];

(* Grid dimension *)
n = 4;

(* Generate partition function *)
Z = Product[1 + σ[i, j] ** σ[i + 1, j] t, {i, 1, n - 1}, {j, 1, n}] * 
    Product[1 + σ[i, j] ** σ[i, j + 1] t, {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n - 1}];

(* Auxiliary function to retrieve diagrams. *)
(* First, retrieve the coefficient of t^exp. *)
(* Then, expand terms and keep only those where each σ appears even times. *)
(* Finally, convert product of 2 σs to a directed edge. *)
(* Results are memoized. *)
getEdges[exp_] := 
 getEdges[exp] = 
  Select[Flatten[{Expand@Coefficient[Z, t^exp]} /. {0} -> {} /. 
        Plus -> List], 
      AllTrue[Tally[Cases[#, σ[__], All]][[All, 2]], EvenQ] &] /. Times -> List /. 
    NonCommutativeMultiply -> UndirectedEdge /. σ[i_, j_] :> {i, j}

(* Generate grid graph *)
gG = GridGraph[{n, n}];
g = Graph[VertexReplace[gG, 
    Thread[VertexList[gG] -> Rationalize@GraphEmbedding[gG]]], 
   VertexLabels -> Automatic];

(* Auxiliary function to plot diagrams. *)
showDiagrams[exp_] := With[{diagrams = getEdges[exp]},
  Grid[Partition[
    HighlightGraph[g, #, GraphHighlightStyle -> "Thick"] & /@ 
     diagrams, Ceiling[Sqrt[Length[diagrams]]], Ceiling[Sqrt[Length[diagrams]]], 
      {1, 1}, Nothing], Spacings -> {3, 3}]]
```

Now you can plot the diagrams for $t^6$ ...

```
showDiagrams[6]
```

[image: Diagrams for t^6]

... or $t^{16}$ (be patient, it takes a few minutes the first time).

```
showDiagrams[16]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Obviously, this approach of getting all diagrams is suitable only for small grids. For larger grids (since you know that the result is simply all possible lattice animals of size $n$), you should pick some other, more efficient algorithm.

Comment: This code is working beautifully for n=4. But it is not working n>4.  Why is that? Thank you!

Comment: @felix, as I've written in the end, if you just want to generate all possible loops, then you should find another method instead of going all the way from Ising partition function which is very inefficient.